# Tangent bundle of a trivial bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, tangent-bundle

I was asking myself if the tangent bundle of a trivial bundle $\mathcal{P}=M\times V$ with fiber $\pi: \mathcal{P}\to M$ (actually it would be a principal trivial bundle, but I think it doesn't matter for the question), where $V$ is a vector space (where a certain group $G$ acts), has same fibers of the tangent bundle over $M$, so if this holds:

$$T_p\mathcal{P}=T_xM,$$

where $p\in \mathcal{P}$ such that $\pi(p)=x\in M$.$$$$
And therefore $$\bigcup_{p\in \mathcal P} \{p\}\times T_p \mathcal P = V \times \bigcup_{x\in M}\{x\}\times T_x M .$$

*edit: of course (according to last equation too) $T_p\mathcal{P}=T_xM\oplus V,$

Comment: First, it is not "the same", at best, they can be canonically isomorphic. And second $T_p\mathcal{P}$ has the same dimension as $\mathcal{P}$, and $T_xM$ has the same dimension as $M$, so they can not possibly be isomorphic, unless $V$ is trivial. What you have is $T_p\mathcal{P}\simeq T_xM\oplus V$, this might extend to a bundle isomorphism, but you'll have to check carefully if the isomorphism can be made canonical globally.

Comment: Surely you know it is not good to use all caps?  This has been the norm on the internet for a quarter century or more. If you didn't know, well, let me be the first to welcome you to the internet!

Comment: Thanks for reporting the error. I immediately corrected it, otherwise last equation did not hold. 
I also thought about the different dimensions, but I don't know out turn this around: I am reading on a paper that that if I have $\sigma : M\to\mathcal P$ a trivializing section, then I can pull back algebra valued differential forms $\textbf A_{\mu} \in \Omega^1(\mathcal P, \mathfrak g)$ to $\textbf A_{\mu} \in \Omega^1(M, \mathfrak g)$.

Comment: Since they are sections on a certain tensor product bundle I would say that if that holds, then $\sigma ^* \mathcal P \times \mathfrak g \otimes T^*\mathcal P \simeq  M \times \mathfrak g \otimes T^*M$  must be holding as well and hence, since a pull-back bundle "shares same fibers" of the bundle, follows what I asked.

Comment: I explain better what I mean: since in general $\Omega^1(M, V)=\Gamma(M\times V \otimes T^*M)$ then a pull-back section is a section on the pull-back bundle (right?) which then shares same fibers (right?). So they should share same fibers, but apparently they do not, so I was trying to figure that out...

Comment: Since your original question ("What is the tangent bundle of a trivial bundle?") is quite a bit simpler than your question in the comments ("How do $1$-forms in a principal bundle push down to $1$-forms on the base space?") it's probably a good idea to ask a new question to address it specifically. Then it's more likely that people will see it, especially if someone has the same question later. Also, you may find what you're looking for here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462613/one-form-on-quotient-manifold

Comment: That being said, if you take a trivializing section $\sigma\colon M\to P$ where $P$ is the underling principal $O(n)$-bundle of $TM$, then any form $\omega\in\Gamma((P\times\mathfrak{g})\otimes T^*P)$ pulls back to $\sigma^*\omega\in \Gamma((M\times\mathfrak{g})\otimes \sigma^*T^*P)$. The bundles $T^*M$ and $\sigma^*T^*P$ do NOT have the same fibres, but choosing a connection gives us an embedding $TM\to TP$ and by contravariance a map the other way $T^*P\to T^*M$, and I think you need to compose your $\sigma^*\omega$ with the map to get a form on $M$.

Comment: Well I don't understand then, because I read on this paper that pulling back $\omega\in\Omega^1(\mathcal P,\mathfrak g)$ via $\sigma:M\to\mathcal P$ gives me a form in $\Omega^1(M,\mathfrak g)$. But then, since the form is on the pull-back bundle, and $\Omega^1(M,\mathfrak g)=\Gamma(M\times\mathfrak g\otimes T^*M)$, the pull-back bundle must be $M\times\mathfrak g\otimes T^*M$. It follows that $\sigma^*T^*\mathcal P$ shares same fibers with $T^*M$. What's wrong?

Comment: Moreover I have also read that given a fiber bundle $\pi:E\to 
 M$ and $f:M' \to M$ then $f^*E$ and $E$ share same fibers over $x'\in M'$ and $x=f(x')\in M$.

Answer (score 1):

In general for a bundle of smooth manifolds $N\to E \to M$ with projection $\pi$, locally $E$ looks like $U_x\times N$ for $U_x$ an neighbourhood of $x\in M$, and wrt to this chart the tangent space at a point $(x,y)$ looks like $T_{(x,y)}E\cong T_xM\times T_yN$. There is even a short exact sequence of bundles

$$ ker(D\pi) \to TE \to TM $$

and choice of connection on $E$ corresponds to a choice of splitting for this sequence, and hence a direct sum decomposition of $TE$ into "vertical" and "horizontal" vectors.

Now let $M^n$ be a smooth manifold, $TM$ its tangent bundle. At any point $(x, v)$ in $TM$ the tangent bundle looks like $T_{(x,v)}\cong T_pM\times T_vT_pM\cong \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, so the fibres of $TTM\to TM$ have twice the dimension as the fibres of $TM \to M$. In fact if we assume as in your question that our tangent bundle is trivial, then there is a global isomorphism

$$ T(TM) \cong TM \times \mathbb{R}^{2n} $$

Comment: Thank you very much, I still have problems with what I wrote in the comment section under my question. If you could take a look I would be glad!